# How to add the value of a array into a ArrayList in stead of the location of that array?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, location

If you add a int[][] to a list, it will not add the value of the array, but the location of the array. How can I add the value of an array to a list. This is the code (This is just an example and might have small errors in it):

```
public class Main {
    int[][] matrix = new int[2][2];
    List<int[2][2]> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            matrixList.add(matrix);
            matrix = matrixCalc(matrix);
        }       

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixList.get(i)));
        }
      public int[][] matrixCalc(int[][] m){
        //do various calculations with m
        ...

        return m;
      }
   }
}
```

I want the output to have different matrixes that are calculated by the calculate method.

example of out put i want to get:

```
{{0,1}{5,7}}
{{2,0}{2,4}}
{{8,1}{4,8}}
{{3,3}{7,9}}
```

output I would get this way (WRONG!)

```
  {{3,3}{7,9}}
  {{3,3}{7,9}}
  {{3,3}{7,9}}
  {{3,3}{7,9}}
```

Comment: in matrixCalc you are changing the same array instance, not a new one, so you are adding to the list the same instance 4 time.

Comment: `List<int[2][2]> matrixList = new ArrayList<>()` -  mindblowingly complicated structure!

Comment: Have a look at [SO40480](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). Your list only contains multiple references to one object.

Comment: @fantarama I get why its working this way, but I want to add the value of matrix to a list while keeping the variable matrix the same. Do you know how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After OP's comment I removed my entire answer ([you can still find a screenshot of it here](http://s30.postimg.org/yqsbtqyr5/Untitled.png); or look in the history of the edits).

> If I'm not mistaken, you send an empty Array to the method matrixCalc? For the calculations method I need a matrix with the same value as I just put on top of the stack.

In that case it's a bit different, although the problem is still having the same reference to `matrix`, so we'll have to change this. To copy the data from one 2D-array to a new one (with a new reference), we should make a separate copy-method. In Java there is the `Arrays.copyOf`-method (or alternatively `System.arraycopy`) for a 1D-array, but for a 2D-array you should make a method yourself. So your code becomes something like this:

```
public class Main {
    int[][] previousMatrix = new int[2][2];
    List<int[2][2]> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int[][] matrix = matrixCalc(previousMatrix);
            matrixList.add(matrix);
            previousMatrix = copy2dArray(matrix);
        }       

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixList.get(i)));
        }
    }

    public int[][] matrixCalc(int[][] m){
        //do various calculations with m
        ...

        return m;
    }

    private int[][] copy2dArray(int[][] original){
        int[][] copy = new int[original.length][];
        for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
            copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(original[i], original[i].length);
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make a new 2D array at the start of your `matrixCalc` method and fill and return that, instead of the parameter given. But, since I didn't knew what kind of calculations you are doing in your `matrixCalc` method I can't really give an example of this. It will look something like this:

```
public int[][] matrixCalc(int[][] m){
    int[][] n = new int[2][2];
    //do various calculations with m,
    //but save the result in n
    ...

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. If I'm not mistaken, you send an empty Array to the method matrixCalc? For the calculations method I need a matrix with the same value as I just put on top of the stack.

Comment: I think this might be the solution! I'll add it to my code and hope for the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
public class Main {
    int[][] matrix = new int[2][2];
    List<int[2][2]> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            matrixList.add(matrixCalc(matrix));
        }       

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixList.get(i)));
        }
      public int[][] matrixCalc(int[][] m){
        int[][] newMatrix = new int[2][2];

        ... do calc then put results on newMatrix

        return newMatrix;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: matrix = new int[2][2]; clears the matrix and adds {{0,0}{0,0}} to the matrixList. I have also tried to put that after the matrixList.add(matrix), but then it clears the matrix and every matrix inside the list aswell.

Comment: I've edited the code, use the matrix variable to hold the state, but matrixCalc must return a new matrix

Comment: I dont want to keep calculating with the same matrix, the output of matrixCalc should be the next matrix I calculate with. For exampel: matrix = 3 --> MatrixList.add(3) --> matrixCalc(3) --> matrix = 5 --> MatrixList.add(5) --> matrixCalc(5) --> matrix = 2 --> matrixList.add(2) -- matrixCalc(2). It is a recursive method that saves every output of matrixCalc to a list and then cals matrixCalc with the matrix returned from matrixCalc

Comment: so post the matrixCalc real code, otherwise how we could understand that is a recursive function? However the problem is still the same, you need to add to the list new instances.

Answer (score 0):

Some background info:
The programm I'm writing uses backtracking. I need to save boardstates into an stack and also add stuff to the board. Here [matrix] stands for the board and [matrixList] for the saved boardstates. When I do calculations I need to have the current board then after I changed something. I need to add the new board on top of the stack and continue changing the new board.

Comment: Next time please put this as an EDIT in the question, since this isn't an answer..

Comment: I didntt found a button for it sorry, will look for it ;)

Comment: Right below your post you should see: _share  **edit**  delete  flag_

Comment: I got it! Do I need to delete the question or can I leave it on here like this? I just got the right awnser.

Comment: All questions can just stay here to help others with the same problem. :) And glad I could help (since you've accepted my answer).